# Porting from Form to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have piece of Code in Form that works:

```
public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
       port.Parent = this;
    }
}
```

now I changed to WPF:

```
public partial class MainWindow : RibbonWindow
{
    private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       port.Parent = this;
    }
}
```

then it gives me:
**"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'"**

What is the problem?

Comment: Like the answers explain the problem in it's basic form is that `port.Parent` expects a certain type of object (forms.control) and you are trying to give it another type. It's like you are assigning a `double` to a `int` variable. You are expecting Forms and WPF to be the same thing because they do similiar things (GUI) but they aren't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using WPF and Windows forms in one application. You cannot use a Windows Forms window as a parent for a WPF window. You should convert both Windows to WPF, or host your WPF elements in a Windows Forms ElementHost control, using a WinForms window.

Comment: The Form's code is in a Form application and the WPF's code is in a separate WPF application. I'm not using both in one application

Comment: This 'port' in the MainWindow is some kind of windows forms element. You are trying to assign it's parent to a WPF control, which does not work. You can use a WindowsFormsHost to host your 'port' element in WPF.

Comment: Actually you can place a WPF window within a Windows Form window through the use of a user control.  Of course this clarification does help the author who clearly has no idea what they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Because all wpf controls are sub types of DependencyObject, you can't give the parent a non DependencyObject instance, and this is the problem.